# Using JavaScript how do I pass a value from a parent form to a child form?

Tags: javascript

I have tried numerous things to no avail. What I am trying to do sounds simple...ASP.NET 2.0. A person enters data in 1 field. I then want them to click a button, this opens a form using window.open whereby the data they entered should be display.

All the examples I find are either incomplete or go from child to parent instead of parent to child.

Comment: Source code? And what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

append this info to the querystring in your window.open logic then pull that data out of the querystring when the child page loads via javascript or serverside scripting.

jquery querystring plugin
http://plugins.jquery.com/project/query-object